# emacs: show date like 'n days ago'

Tags: date, emacs, formatting

At the moment, my RSS feed shows dates using this function

```
(format-time-string "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M" (seconds-to-time date))
```

I want to display the date like "N days ago"

Is this possible with emacs lisp?

Comment: Your example begins with the premise that DATE is the form of *seconds*, and you then convert it to a TIME format.  How do we know that DATE is in the form of *seconds* to begin with?  One does not normally (at least myself) think of a date as being in the form of seconds.  With that being said, the general approach is to convert the date to days (subsequent to BC) and then add N, and then convert the result back again.

Comment: See `time-to-days` and `days-to-time`:  https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs-mime/time_002ddate.html

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
(format "%d days ago"
        (floor
         (/ (float-time (time-subtract (current-time) (seconds-to-time date)))
            (* 60 60 24))))
```